# Displaying a telescoping series

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'd like to show my students what happens with the telescoping series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right]$. For example, I would like to display the partial sum:
$$s_5=\left[1-\frac12\right]+\left[\frac12-\frac13\right]+\left[\frac13-\frac14\right]+\left[\frac14-\frac15\right]+\left[\frac15-\frac16\right]$$
I've not used HoldForm before, but I tried:

```
Table[HoldForm[1/n - 1/(n + 1)], {n, 1, 5}]
```

But that didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Far from perfect, but a bit better : `show[n_?NumericQ] := Defer[1/n - 1/(n + 1)];
Table[show[n], {n, 5}]` outputs `{1 1/1 - 1/(1 + 1), 1/2 - 1/(2 + 1), 1/3 - 1/(3 + 1), 1/4 - 1/(4 + 1),
  1/5 - 1/(5 + 1)}`.

Comment: Or, better, this `show[n_?NumericQ] := Block[{m = n + 1}, Inactivate[1/n - 1/m, Plus]]`:

Comment: Do you think it is a valid duplicate: [Getting terms and only evaluate specific parts](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71938/5478)?

Comment: Related: [110532](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110529/expand-series-unevaluated/110532)

Comment: I'd like to thank all my colleagues for tremendous help. There is a lot to learn here and some great examples to share with my students.

Answer (score 9):

In the following way you can get the printed result you are asking for:

```
lst=Table[1/n, {n, 1,6}];
Inactive[Plus] @@ MapThread[Defer[Subtract[##]]& ,{Most[lst], Rest[lst]}]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

Here is another, simpler, solution:

```
HoldForm[1 - 1/2] + Sum[With[{n = n, m = n + 1}, HoldForm[1/n - 1/m]], {n, 2, 5}]
```

When we would have started the summation with `n=1` instead of `n=2`, the very first number `1/1` would have turned up as `1*1/1`, which is not what we want. Compare [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69655/20253). An acceptable output is given by:

```
Sum[With[{n=n, m=n+1}, HoldForm[Divide[1,n]-Divide[1,m]]], {n,1,5}]
```

Comment: @egwene sedai. Many thanks for including the output!

Comment: I think you need to make two edits, as in: Sum[With[{n=n,m=n+1},HoldForm[Divide[1,n]-Divide[1,m]]],{n,1,5}] and HoldForm[1 - 1/2] + Sum[With[{n = n,m = n + 1}, HoldForm[1/n - 1/m]], {n, 2, 5}]. Awesome answer.

Comment: @David. You are right that I do not need the three arguments form of With. So I edited my answer accordingly..

Answer (score 4):

Here's a start, first by inactivating `Plus` everywhere, then reactivating it in the denominators:

```
ReplaceAll[
 Block[{Plus = Inactive[Plus]}, Sum[1/i - 1/(i + 1), {i, 1, 5}]],
 -Inactive[Plus][v__]^(-1) :> -Plus[v]^(-1)
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Simpler is `Inactivate[Sum[1/i - 1/(i+1), {i, 5}], Plus]` although it isn't equivalent because `Sum` produces an active `Plus`.

Comment: @CarlWoll It is simpler to write, but the result gets reordered when I use `Inactivate`. I do not fully understand why, but I wanted to retain the ordering shown in OP.

Answer (score 2):

```
d = Table[If[n == 1, 1, 1/ToString[n]] - 1/ToString[n + 1], {n, 1, 5}];
s = "[" <> ToString[d[[1]], StandardForm] <> "]";

For[ii = 2, ii <= Length[d], ii++,
 s = s <> "+[" <> ToString[d[[ii]], StandardForm] <> "]";
 ]
```

[image]